# Entry in one column not existng in all the entries of another column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using below query -

```
 Select B.Backup_datetime, E.date    
    from Table B
            cross apply 
                (select max(E.Backup_datetime) date
                from Table E
                where E.Backup_datetime<B.Backup_datetime) E
```

Creates below result -

```
Backup_datetime     date 
     08              07       
     07              05
     05              04
     04              03
```

Now, I want to see the row with `Backup_datetime` which does not exist in the entire set of `date`. In this case, `'08'` from `Backup_datetime` is not present in the `date` set. So, I want to see only the row with `Backup_datetime`=`'08'`.  How can I append the existing code to get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it. I used a cte so I could reference your original query without having to write it more than once.

```
;with cte as
(
Select B.Backup_datetime, E.date    
    from Table B
            cross apply 
                (select max(E.Backup_datetime) date
                 from Table E
                 where E.Backup_datetime<B.Backup_datetime) E
)

SELECT * FROM cte where backup_datetime NOT IN (select date from cte)
```

Or if you don't want to use a cte

```
Select 
    B.Backup_datetime
  , E.date    
from Table B
  cross apply 
   (select max(E.Backup_datetime) date
    from Table E
    where E.Backup_datetime<B.Backup_datetime)
where
backupdate not in
  (Select E.date    
        from Table B
                cross apply 
                    (select max(E.Backup_datetime) date
                     from Table E
                     where E.Backup_datetime<B.Backup_datetime))
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if I don't want to create  a separate table `cte` and append the existing query instead?

Comment: Smart answer. Worked!

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
SELECT TOP 1 B.Backup_datetime, E.[date]    
FROM Table B
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT MAX(E.Backup_datetime) AS [date]
   FROM Table E
   WHERE E.Backup_datetime<B.Backup_datetime) E
ORDER BY B.Backup_datetime DESC
```

Only the top-most record contains a `Backup_datetime` value that is not present in `[date]` field. The `Backup_datetime` value of any other record is bound to be present in the `[date]` field of the row having the next `Backup_datetime` value.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/431ad/3)